# React Native .map function not returning a View or Text

Tags: react-native, dictionary

I'm writing a map function in React Native and no matter what I have tried, I cant get it to return a View or Text.  The console.log on line 132 returns valid data, so I know its going into the map function, but it is not returning the View. I have tried:

- state.map((stock, i) => {})
- state.map((stock, i) => ())
- state.map((stock,i) =>

I have tried with and without the return(), but it just displays nothing.

```
<ScrollView>
    <Text style={styles.whitetext}>Hello...</Text>
    {state.map((stock, i) => {
        console.log(stock)       
        return (
           <View key={i}>
               <Text style={styles.whitetext} key={i}>test {stock.symbol}</Text>
           </View>
        )
     })}
</ScrollView>
```

[The console.log returning a value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oGFOr.png)
[The displayed screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hdks4.png)

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: What happens if you remove the `<View>` in the return?

Comment: Is `View` being imported?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turned out that a dependency in my useEffect was causing my view to re render multiple times (even though the state constant being mapped here still held the details) and by removing that it rendered properly.  Thanks for your help guys!

Answer (score 0):

```
{state.map((stock, i) => (
 <View key={i}>
               <Text style={styles.whitetext} key={i}>test {stock.symbol}</Text>
           </View>
))}
```

Comment: Some additional explanation would help with further understanding the issue.